# What is the g_init attribute of html tag?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web

What is the g_init attribute of html tag?

Like `<html g_init="6909">` here:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I visit http://php.net in Chrome 38, I don't see this attribute in the HTML.

As has been pointed out, this attribute has no meaning according to any HTML specification.

My guess is that this is inserted by an extension you have running in your browser.

Try navigating to `chrome://extensions/` and disabling extensions, then reloading the page.

Comment: Sure. It's inserted by an extension. Thank you. It was interesting to figure out.

Comment: @PawlikDoc, glad to hear you sorted it out. What extension was causing it? Someone will probably end up here in future, wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

That attribute does not exist according to the HTML specification. See the specs at [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.3).

Available attributes:

- version
- lang
- dir

I guess your `g_init` is an attribute that is picked up by some hand-crafted javascript.

Comment: Ok, I know it, but why so many pages contain this in source code?

Comment: Any examples of that?

Comment: Why does Chrome shows me this in F12 tools? http://cs622931.vk.me/v622931078/c446/8sacc6SSJ0k.jpg

Comment: Ok, you haven't it, but i have. Why? Something with google account maybe?

Comment: Don't know. Maybe some JS, maybe something else, I don't know. It isn't part of the spec for certain.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and figured out it was "friGate CDN" extension

Answer (score 0):

That's for sure from extension. For me it was yandex.sovetnik.

It even cause many lags on site before deactivating this extension.